# Downloading instead of viewing register success in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Here's the problem. when I try to submit the data into my database. Instead of showing the Register success, it ended up downloading the URL which is the RegisterStudent. How do I solve that? I'm a little puzzled here.

Code:

```
public class RegisterStudent extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("REgister succcess");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/pages/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("html/text");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String studentID = request.getParameter("StudentID");
    String firstName = request.getParameter("Firstname");
    String middleName = request.getParameter("Middlename");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("Lastname");
    String age = request.getParameter("Age");
    String gender = request.getParameter("Gender");
    String address = request.getParameter("Address");

    int age1 = Integer.parseInt(age);

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bsitstudentinfos","root","");
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into tb_studentregistration value (null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, studentID);
        ps.setString(2, firstName);
        ps.setString(3, middleName);
        ps.setString(4, lastName);
        ps.setInt(5, age1);
        ps.setString(6, gender);
        ps.setString(7, address);

        int update = ps.executeUpdate();

        if(update>0){

            out.print("The submitted value is added in database");

        }

    }catch(Exception ex){

        System.out.println("Error in database!");

    }
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in doPost method you are setting wrong content type.

```
response.setContentType("html/text");
```

This is not correct mime type, instead you should use **text/html**. Setting wrong mime type is causing your page to download.

Secondly after insertion, you are not redirecting to any success page, instead printing a message which will print under the servlet url i.e. **RegisterStudent**.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are submitting form with get method then it redirecting in
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("REgister succcess");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/pages/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
here either you can print message 'Register success' or you can forward some another page.if you write both then it execute last one so it redirecting in register.jsp page
```